# algorithm for splitting fft into bands

Tags: fft, frequency-spectrum

i already know how to programmatically take the fft of a signal and display it, but now i'm trying to figure out how i can split the full fft into an arbitrary number of bands. i haven't yet been able to figure it out myself, and i can't seem to find any information on the web about this

1. what algorithm could i use for this? i have the feeling it involves some kind of averaging of the bins, but i don't know what kind of averaging it entails
2. if possible, how would i be able to only display a set frequency range with the same number of bars? i know that if the range is too small, then depending on the fft size, the bins won't be able to fill the bars; is there some other interpolation for this?

Comment: One possibility is to use Goertzel on the frequencies you're interested in. If the number of bands is small, I'd use the DTFT directly.

Comment: the goertzel was exactly what i was looking for! thank you!

Answer (score 1):

One approach to consider if efficiency is of utmost concern is to decimate the waveform prior to taking the FFT (and therefore reduce the total number of samples while still maintaining the same resolution BW relative to the original sampling rate).

A decimation which a filtering and then downsample operation can be efficiently done with a series of halfband fitlers, which can include bandpass filters so that the entire bandwidth can be individually selected, or optionally rotate (multiply the signal by $e^{-j \omega_n}$) the signal through a low pass selection filter and then down-sample where $\omega_n$ is the selected band center.

To interpolate the spectrum, simply zero pad the data prior to taking the FFT. This is done in Matlab/Octave and Python by using the second length parameter in the fft function; if the length is longer than the data, it will zero pad it.

When less than 2Log2N DFT coefficients for an N point DFT are of interest, the Goertzel algorithm could be more efficient as MBaz has mentioned in the comments.